# Best practice to read child component value

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I have created a Razor component, a simple input type like this:

```
@using ComponentPackage.Common

<input type="text" @bind="InputValue" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private string inputValue;
    public string InputValue
    {
        get => inputValue;
        set
        {
            inputValue = value;
            ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I setup the child component like this on a Razor page:

```
@page "/newpage"
@using ComponentPackage.Common

<ComponentPackage.Components.TextBox ValueChanged="OnValueChanged"></ComponentPackage.Components.TextBox>
<input type="button" @onclick="TestContent" value="Test" />
<br /><br />
You have entered : @ReturnValue

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string ReturnValue { get; set; }

    private void TestContent()
    {
        // Here I want to get the value from the component
    }

    public void OnValueChanged(string returnValue)
    {
        ReturnValue = returnValue;
    }
}
```

From the page I wire the component event to the OnValueChanged. This works, as soon as I leave the field the ReturnValue property is update.

So the question is: How do I read the value in the textbox when I click the button on the page? In other words, I don't want the ReturnValue to be set when I leave the textbox. I have tried using bind-InputValue to a property on the page, but it is always null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to change it to this : .. so it is using the bind-InputValue instead of binding to the event. But this gives me the following error : Object of type 'ComponentPackage.Components.TextBox' has a property matching the name 'InputValue', but it does not have [ParameterAttribute] or [CascadingParameterAttribute] applied –

If you use the TextBox component in a parent component like this:

```
<TextBox @bind-InputValue="ReturnValue" />
```

You bind the TextBox component to a variable you define in the parent component, like this:

```
private string ReturnValue {get; set;}
```

The ReturnValue property will be updated with values from the TextBox by triggering an EventCallback 'delegate'.

InputValue (used above: @bind-InputValue="ReturnValue") should be defined as a public parameter property like this:

```
[Parameter]
public string InputValue {get; set;}
```

You also need to define, in the child component (named TextBox), a public parameter property for the EventCallback 'delegate', like this:

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<string> InputValueChanged { get; set; }
```

As you can see, we create a pair made of a property and EventCallback

If your property is named InputValue, then your EventCallback should be named InputValueChanged.

If your property is named Value, then your EventCallback should be named ValueChanged.

If your property is named Text, then your EventCallback should be named TextChanged.

They always come in pairs.

Now go back to my first answer, and learn the code, run it test it, enjoy, and don't forget to vote my answer up...

Comment: After reading alot more about bind and generics behind the DOM manipulation, I got the solution I was looking for. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you need: **Two-way databinding in components**
The following code, complete and working is what you want...
Copy, paste and run...

The following sample shows how to perform two-way data-binding between a parent component and its child component. In each of these two component is a text box controls. When you type text in the parent component's text box, the text in the child component's text box changes to reflect the changes made in the parent, and vice versa...

### ChildComponent.razor

```
    <div style="border:solid 1px red">
        <h2>Child Component</h2>
        <input type="text" @bind="Text" @bind:event="oninput" />
    </div>

@code {
    private string text { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set
        {
            if (text != value) {
                text = value;
                if (TextChanged.HasDelegate)
                {
                    TextChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> TextChanged { get; set; }
}
```

### ParentComponent.razor

```
@page "/ParentComponent"

<h1>Parent Component</h1>

<input type="text" @bind="Text" @bind:event="oninput" />
<p></p>

<ChildComponent @bind-Text="Text" />


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Text { get; set; } = "Hello Blazor";
}
```

Add this content to Shared/NavMenu.razor, and test the code:

```
<li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="ParentComponent">
                <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> ParentComponent
            </NavLink>
        </li>
```

Good luck... If something is not clear, don't hesitate to ask...

Comment: I tried to change it to this : <ComponentPackage.Components.TextBox @bind-InputValue="ReturnValue"></ComponentPackage.Components.TextBox>.. so it is using the bind-InputValue instead of binding to the event. But this gives me the following error : Object of type 'ComponentPackage.Components.TextBox' has a property matching the name 'InputValue', but it does not have [ParameterAttribute] or [CascadingParameterAttribute] applied

Comment: I've copied your code and it works, as it did before. I replaced oninput with onchange, so the event is not triggered until I leave the textbox. So I assume this is the "best practice", that you need to bind the value using event callback. And when I press the button, I just need to read the property from the  component where the button is, as the property there has already been updated.

Comment: "And when I press the button, I just need to read the property from the component where the button is, as the property there has already been updated." Exactly. "So I assume this is the "best practice", that you need to bind the value using event callback" Yes, indeed. This is the way to do it. A property that update an element (data flow from variable to element), and an event such as change or input to update the variable (data flow from element to variable ). Would you mind marking it as the answer if it solved your problem, so others know it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

**This is my solution, hope it will help**

I have StateDropdown as a child component

```
@inject HttpClient httpClient

@if (States != null)
{
<select id="SearchStateId" name="stateId" @onchange="@StateChange" class="form-control1">
    <option>@InitialText</option>
    @foreach (var state in States)
    {
        <option value="@state.Name">@state.Name</option>
    }
</select>
}

@code {
[Parameter] public string SelectedText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
[Parameter] public string InitialText { get; set; } = "Select State";
[Parameter] public EventCallback<string> SelectedTextChanged { get; set; }
private KeyValue[] States;
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    States = await httpClient.GetJsonAsync<KeyValue[]>("/sample-data/State.json");
}

private async Task StateChange(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
    //Console.WriteLine("It is definitely: " + e.Value.ToString());
    await SelectedTextChanged.InvokeAsync(e.Value.ToString());
}

public class KeyValue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
}
```

Then in my page, I added State dropdown with

```
<StateDropdown @bind-SelectedText="@searchFilter.State" InitialText="All India"></StateDropdown>
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" class="btn-default form-control1" @onclick="@SearchAdertisements" value="Search" />


@code {
 private SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter();
 public class SearchFilter
{
    public string State { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string Category { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

private async Task SearchAdertisements()
{
    Console.WriteLine(searchFilter.State);
}
```

you can [read](https://blazor-university.com/components/two-way-binding/) for more detail.

Comment: Interesting approach for select, will probably use this later. Thanks. But as I see it, you still need the event to bind it to the parent component property and when changed/leave, the callback event do the trick to sync. I was looking for a way, that when you press the button in the parent, then it somehow ask the child, what is the value in your textbox. But as a read other articles, this is no simple call for this approach.